# Software for batch renaming of images

Tags: images, gui, rename, filenames

I have a bunch of images downloaded from the web. I kept their original file names when I saved them.

Now I would like to reorder these images and have them renamed in a pattern like this: `[prefix]_[sequence_number].[original_file_extension]`

So, for example, I have reordered the images and want the prefix `japan`, I would like to have the following result:

japan_1.jpg
japan_2.jpg
japan_3.jpg
japan_4.jpg
japan_5.jpg
...

Is there any GUI application on Windows/MAC that can be helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) (for Windows) has a built-in image Batch Conversion/Rename tool with tons of options.

Comment: can it rename the images according to the custom image order defined by user?

Comment: @bobo: [here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/EMi6X.png) of the tool. There are several ways to sort the input files

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It looks good but the image preview is missing in the `Input files` list, this makes the reordering process still quite painful.

Comment: @bobo: If you select the input files one by one then it shows a preview image (on my screenshot where it says "No preview possible!" since I've selected multiple files). And you can always click the View Menu and select Thumbnails to see thumbnails of all the files in the current folder

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that. It seems to fit my needs. This is probably the best freeware available on Windows that can do such thing. Thank you very very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)